# How to set the android application logo and launcher icon programmatically

Tags: android

Would it be possible to set the logo and launcher icon dynamically rather than specifying in the manifest

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:logo="@drawable/app_logo"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Comment: The icon shown on the homescreen / app drawer can AFAIK not be changed at runtime since that icon needs to be available to the system without your code even running. That's why it is defined in the manifest (which is not modifiable through code).

Answer (score 4):

Call `setIcon()` and `setLogo()` on `ActionBar` to change them at runtime.

EDIT: Works from API level 14 on.